# 'Access violation writing location ...' from managed .NET code

Tags: c#, .net

I am getting the following exception:

> Unhandled exception at 0x000007FE21AFE593 (mscorlib.ni.dll) in MqSearch.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0x00000006609476FD.

- Code is a fully managed .net C# program
- .net framework 4.5
- Windows Server 2012
- Happens in full processing load on a system with 64 logical processors
- Does not happen deterministically. Seems to be crashing at different numbers of iterations, although the code is 100% deterministic, in the sense that no random number generator is used.
- Crashing rate is about once per day
- Crashes on an AMD system (Dell PowerEdge 815). On a similar Intel system (Dell PowerEdge 820) no problems occur
- I tried in the app.config to disable gcConcurrent which did not help.
- Unfortunately this does not produce a stack trace to managed code. Only some assembly stack trace to KernelBase.dll is generated.

IMO this should not be happening. If you have any idea what could be going on or what I could try, I'd be very grateful.

Comment: You need to get a .DMP file (Generate with WinDBG) and have it analyzed, since this error shouldn't be possible without PInvoke unless there's a Windows API or Managed API bug in the framework itself. First, you should run the Windows Memory Diagnostic to rule out a memory fault.

Comment: Access violations are produced by unsafe code.  There's plenty of it inside mscorlib.dll.  You get it to crash by using threads and not locking properly.  Bad RAM chips are technically possible as well.

Comment: Thanks so far. Quick update: -Windows Memory Diagnostic does not find any problems. -code is single threaded. Multiple cores are used by running 64 executables. -no PInvoke is used by me. -no unsafe code is used.

Comment: That said, I conclude that it is an AMD specific bug in mscorlib.dll. Has anybody seen anything like that, or experience with AMD specific bugs and knowledge how to avoid them?