# How can I resolve an access violation in managed C# code with structs?

Tags: c#, access-violation

**Problem:** When I attempt to access a derived property of a C# `struct`, it results in an access violation error and the application exits abruptly (with status 0xC0000005). Unlike [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16568871/access-violation-writing-location-from-managed-net-code), it happens deterministically on a single property.

The struct definition is in a different library however I control both the client application and the library where the struct is defined.

There is no unmanaged code that I've written for this project. I'm using .NET 5 in both the client application and the library.

**Things I've Tried:**

1. Changing the output to x64 in the library didn't help (the application output is x64)
2. Enabling native code debugging (no information was provided)

**MCVE:**

Definition

```cs
public struct Foo
{
    public const Double BarDivisor = 100.0;

    // ...other properties...

    public Int64 BarWholePart { get; }
    public Int64 BarFractionalPart { get; }
    public Double Bar => Bar + (BarFractionalPart / BarDivisor);
    
    public Foo(Int64 wholePart, Int64 fractionalPart, /* ... */)
    {
        // ...
        BarWholePart = wholePart;
        BarFractionalPart = fractionalPart;
    }

    public static Foo Parse(Int64 whole, Int64 fractional)
    {
        return new Foo(whole, fractional);
         // ...
    }
}
```

Example of calling code

```cs
public void Baz(Foo bar)
{
    // ...
    Double foobar = bar.Bar; // this line results in a crash of the application
    // ...
}
```

**Exception Messages:**

> Exception thrown at 0x00007FF8C85A21A0 (coreclr.dll) in [application name removed]: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0x000000E70B180FF8.
>
> The Common Language Runtime cannot stop at this exception. Common causes include: incorrect COM interop marshalling and memory corruption. To investigate further use native-only debugging.
>
> Unhandled exception at 0x00007FF8C85A21A0 (coreclr.dll) in [application name removed]: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0x000000E70B180FF8.
>
> The Common Language Runtime cannot stop at this exception. Common causes include: incorrect COM interop marshalling and memory corruption. To investigate further use native-only debugging.

Comment: Not sure this is reproducible the way it's written. Maybe create a GitHub repository with a reproduce?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is caused because of a typographical error here

```
public Double Bar => Bar + (BarFractionalPart / BarDivisor);
```

`BarWholePart` should be used instead of `Bar`. This causes a StackOverflowException, but can sometimes cause an AccessViolationException in the debugger.

Comment: Oh man that was a life saver. I didn't realize StackOverflowException could manifest as AccessViolationException. Couldn't for the life of me figure out how I could be causing a native memory error but sure enough it was a stack overflow!